# Return count using raw query, using Entity Framework and MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework in an MVC website

I am trying to get just the number of records using a raw query.

I am looking for something along these lines but any will be happy with any solution at all.

```
var sql = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Articles WHERE (CategoryID = 3)

var total = _context.Database.SOMETHING(sql)
```

I realise that for such a simple scenario, a raw query is perhaps not the way to go but in reality, the sql string is MUCH more complicated so it is next to impossible for to use Linq to SQL.

Comment: What is the type of `_context`? `DbContext`, `DataContext`, `ObjectContext` ?

Comment: @nemesv. It is a DbContext ( sorry, it did not realise that Entity Framework could have different things - I am obviously new to this game). Does knowing it is DbContext mean you can help me?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can [execute raw SQL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/02/04/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-10-raw-sql-queries.aspx) queries with EF code first with using the [SqlQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679164%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method:

```
var sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Articles WHERE (CategoryID = 3)";
var total = _context.Database.SqlQuery<int>(sql).First();
```

Comment: Brilliant! That worked perfectly after I changed the last line to

var total = _context.Database.SqlQuery<int>(sql).single();

Comment: But i have to use dynamic as below,  var sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Articles"; dynamic total = _context.Database.SqlQuery<dynamic>(sql).ToList();  ..... Is this possible??

Answer (score 4):

An update for the approved answer above with a EF Core 7.

1. name the column 'AS Value'. It must be named like this, it fails otherwise.
2. use SqlQueryRaw because SqlQuery requires a FormattableString and 'sql' is not such. However, it can be re-written with SqlQuery.

```
var sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Value FROM dbo.Articles WHERE (CategoryID = 3)";
var total = _context.Database.SqlQueryRaw<int>(sql).First();
```

with SqlQuery

```
int categoryId = 3;
var total = _context.Database.SqlQueryRaw<int>($"SELECT COUNT(*) AS Value FROM dbo.Articles WHERE (CategoryID = {categoryId})").First();
```

Comment: Adding 'AS Value' works well in EF Core 7, thanks! You can use SqlQuery (not only SqlQueryRaw) if using interpolated strings for parameterization.